# How to make an sql query to build a tree?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado.net, treeview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store directory / hierarchy / tree structure in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144344/how-to-store-directory-hierarchy-tree-structure-in-the-database)

I use this query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId
FROM Table_1
```

And then I build the tree using all elements.

But what if I want to build a tree that starts from definite `Id`, so I need to make a query that returns only this `Id` and all childs of this `Id` 
Like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId
FROM Table_1
WHERE (Id = randomNumber) OR (all possible childs of Id = randomNumber)
```

Help me please to make a query.

EDIT:

This is how you can make it in Oracle

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId
FROM table_1
Connect by prior Id = ParentId
Start with Id = randomNumber
```

I need MS-Access

Comment: You want to get the children of the parentid and the children of children, etc. right?

Comment: @András Ottó, Does it matter ?

Comment: Yes, because if it is only one level deep, you can pick up one from those two anawers:) If it is more then you need more, a recursive solution what you can manage with stored procedure f.e. But I got the answer, I wanted to know what devundef asked:)

Comment: @András Ottó, it's not only one level deep, it might be more

Comment: @András Ottó, could you enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted on the related post, this cannot be done using SQL alone, however it can be done using a combination of SQL and VBA relatively easy.

The goal is for a specified `Id` to return that record and all of its children. As a result, all you need is a boolean function which returns true when the row `Id` is a direct descendant of the specified ancestor.

Your SQL would be:

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId
FROM Table_1
WHERE IsDescendant(Id, randomNumber);
```

The VBA function in Access would be:

```
Public Function IsDescendant(id As Integer, relative As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim currentID As Variant
    currentID = id

    Do Until IsNull(currentID)
        If (currentID = relative) Then
            IsDescendant = True
            Exit Function
        End If
        currentID = DLookup("ParentId", "Table_1", "Id=" & currentID)
    Loop
    IsDescendant = False
End Function
```

Performance-wise this may not be the greatest because I used `DLookup` but we could also use `RecordSet` objects if there are significant performance gains to be had. This is just the quickest code I could jot down.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @ID int

SET @ID = 1;

WITH CTE_Table_1
(
 ID,
 Name,
 ParentID,
 TreeLevel
)
AS(
  SELECT 
   ID,
   Name,
   ParentID,
   0 AS TreeLevel
  FROM Table_1
  WHERE ID = @ID

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
   T.ID,
   T.Name,
   T.ParentID,
   TreeLevel + 1
  FROM Table_1 T
  INNER JOIN CTE_Table_1 ON CTE_Table_1.ID = T.ParentID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table on itself linking the parent id to the child id

```
SELECT T1.Id, T1.Name, T2.Id, T2.Name
FROM   Table_1 as T1
JOIN   Table_1 as T2 on T1.Id = T2.ParentId
```

Given the data

```
Id, Name       ParentId
1,  Top,        null
2,  ChildOne,   1
3,  ChildTwo,   1
4,  ChildThree, 1
```

This will give you a result like

```
1,   Top,    2, ChildOne
1,   Top,    3, ChildTwo
1,   Top,    4, ChildFour
```

Comment: And if you have multiple dependences, not just two but three level? You can't get the child of the childs of the given id.

Comment: If you want it to be recursive, then you'd probably be looking at a recursive list building stored proc?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, this should do the trick

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId 
FROM Table_1 
WHERE (Id = randomNumber) OR (ParentId = randomNumber)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only build one level of the tree?

Comment: this retuns only root and childs of this root, but where is the childs of the childs ?

Comment: danm it, you're right of course.  try andras' answer.